# How to call .NET Core Web Api from another service, both running in separate docker containers

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

In my scenario, I have two .NET Core Web Apis that are running on two separate docker containers.

The first service is called `Catalog.API` and this is the code of the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Catalog.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Catalog.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CatalogController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CatalogItemContext _context;

        public CatalogController(CatalogItemContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [Route("items")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<CatalogItem>>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            var items = await _context.CatalogItems.ToListAsync();
            if (items == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return items;
        }

        [Route("items/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CatalogItem>> GetItemByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var item = await _context.CatalogItems.SingleOrDefaultAsync(model => model.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return item;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("items")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProductAsync([FromBody] CatalogItem product)
        {
            var item = new CatalogItem(product.Name, product.Price, product.Count);
            _context.CatalogItems.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItemByIdAsync), new {id = item.Id}, null);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("items")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateProductAsync([FromBody] CatalogItem productToUpdate)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Entry(productToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItemByIdAsync), new {id = productToUpdate.Id}, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("items/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteProductById(int id)
        {
            var itemToDelete = _context.CatalogItems.SingleOrDefault(model => model.Id == id);
            if (itemToDelete == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.CatalogItems.Remove(itemToDelete);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have some basic methods, nothing special so far. This service is running on `localhost:80` (For example, `http://localhost:80/api/catalog/items`)

This is the dockerfile for the Catalog.API, that is getting called via docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj /src/csproj-files/

WORKDIR ./csproj-files
RUN dotnet restore


WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

The second Service is called `Basket.API` and this is the controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Basket.API.Models;
using Basket.API.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Basket.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BasketController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BasketContext _context;
        private readonly IBasketService _basketService;

        public BasketController(BasketContext context, IBasketService basketService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _basketService = basketService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("entries")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Models.Basket>>> GetAllBasketAsync()
        {
            var basketList = await _context.UserBaskets.Include(basket => basket.Items).ToListAsync(); //include needed to load Items List
            if (basketList == null)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }

            return basketList;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("entries/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Models.Basket>> GetBasketByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var basket = await _context.UserBaskets.Where(b => b.UserId == id).Include(m => m.Items).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            if (basket == null)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }

            return basket;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> TestCall()
        {
            var test1 = await _basketService.GetBasketByIdAsync(1);
            return Ok(test1);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the controller, I am using a class called BasketService that gets injected in the `Startup.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Basket.API.Models;
using Basket.API.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Basket.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<BasketContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
            });

            services.AddHttpClient<IBasketService, BasketService>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the `BasketService.cs`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Basket.API.Services
{
    public class BasketService : IBasketService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public BasketService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }
        
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Basket>> GetAllBasketAsync()
        {
            var stringContent = await _client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:80/api/basket/entries");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.Basket>>(stringContent);
        }

        public async Task<Models.Basket> GetBasketByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var stringContent = await _client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:80/api/basket/entries/" + id);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Basket>(stringContent);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Basket.API` is running on `localhost:81` and this is the Dockerfile, that gets also called by the docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 81

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Basket.API.csproj /src/csproj-files/

WORKDIR ./csproj-files
RUN dotnet restore

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Basket.API.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sqldata:
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
  
  catalog.api:
    ports:
      - 80:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata

  basket.api:
    ports:
      - 81:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
```

My goal is to call the `Catalog.API` out of the `BasketService.cs` class by using a http client. As you might already noticed, I tried calling the Web Api using `localhost:80` but this is not working, because both Apis are running on different containers and localhost is only valid for the Basket container (where I have the BasketService class). I am unsure, how to call the Catalog.API, correctly. I can look up the IP of the container manually by using `docker inspect <dockerid>`, but every time I restart or rebuild the containers, the ip changes. So this is not a good way. Using the service name didn't work.

What is the best way to resolve this issue? Which way should I use to call the Api, running on another container?

Comment: You can use the name of the `services:` block of each service as a host name, within the same `docker-compose.yml` file; connect to the port the process inside the container is listening on (80, in this case, for both containers).  You don't specifically need a `ports:` declaration if you don't want to access the service from outside Docker.  `localhost` in Docker almost always means "this container".

Comment: @joey I don't know what you mean by "chained api calls", but calling one api form another api while both implemented in different services is the way to build micro-services. You hardly can call micro-services bad practice when whole the industry moving there.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Thank you for your answer. I changed to using the service name as host and it works as expected. The ports are there because as of now, i am accessing the containers outside docker for testing the outcome.

Comment: @Artur : Thanks for the clarification, and some point i was kinda confused by the comment of joey . But as you said, its kinda the way how you build them.

Comment: Hi @Artur, so what "chained api calls" means is exactly what it sounds like : 1 api dependent on another api during a request/response lifecycle. Perhaps it sounds confusing if you are hearing of it for the first time. "Moreover, having HTTP dependencies between microservices, like when creating long
request/response cycles with HTTP request chains, as shown in the first part of the Figure 4-15, not
only makes your microservices not autonomous but also their performance is impacted as soon as
one of the services in that chain isn’t performing well."

Comment: "Therefore, in order to enforce microservice autonomy and have better resiliency, you should minimize
the use of chains of request/response communication across microservices. It’s recommended that
you use only asynchronous interaction for inter-microservice communication, either by using
asynchronous message- and event-based communication, or by using (asynchronous) HTTP polling
independently of the original HTTP request/response cycle." I highly recommend reading up on these best practices here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/microservices-architecture-ebook

Answer (score 0):

You must create a network to comunicate both containers

docker network create your-network
docker network connect your-network the-service-container

then, you can write
_client.GetStringAsync("http://the-service-container:80/api/basket/entries");